# How to double values in 2d array? C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to double each number in 2D arrays. For example the values in `array1` would become `{2,4,6}{4,8,12}{6,12,18}`. The problem is that my code doubles the only the first number. Can someone give me some direction on what to do?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 

const int N = 3; 

int doubleValues(int arr[][N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        arr[i][N] *= 2; 

        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            arr[N][j] *= 2;
            return arr[i][j]; 
        }
    }   
}

void showArray(int arr[][N])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl; 
     }
}

int main()
{
    int array1 [N][N] = {
        { 1, 2, 3 } ,
        { 2, 4, 6 } ,
        { 3, 6, 9 } 
    };

    int array2 [N][N] = {
        { 3, 4, 5 } ,
        { 6, 8, 10 } ,
        { 9, 12, 15 } 
    };

    cout << "The values for array1 doubled are: \n";
    doubleValues(array1);
    showArray(array1);

    cout << "The values for array2 double are: \n";
    doubleValues(array2);
    showArray(array2);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Advice: Do not use any array function arguments whatsoever (use pointers with  additional size information). Avoid multiple-dimensional arrays. Use templates, if you want to pass an array extent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `return arr[i][j]` in the inner loop of your `doubleValues` function. After doubling the first element, your function returns without doing any more work.

The solution is to remove this `return` statement. (And change `doubleValues` to a `void` function, because it doesn't need to return a value.)

Also, your `doubleValues` function seems to be modifying the wrong elements anyway. Both your accesses to `arr[i][N]` and `arr[N][j]` access elements out of bounds of your declared array size. You should probably be modifying `arr[i][j]` within your loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `std::array` for this project (since you know the size of your array at compile time) , you can use the functions within the `<algorithm>` header to easily implement your `doubleValues` function and not worry about hand-writing the loops.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t size>
void doubleValues(std::array<T,size>& arr)
{
    std::transform(std::begin(arr),std::end(arr),std::begin(arr), [](auto x) { return 2 * x; });
}
```

This method would require that you break your 2d-array structure down into a single dimension, which can be accomplished with relative ease. For example,

```
std::array<int,N*N> array1 = { 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9 };
std::array<int,N*N> array2 = { 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10, 9, 12, 15}
```

In the case where the size of the arrays could change dynamically, you can swap out `std::array` for `std::vector`.